# How to Remove all the HTML tags and display a plain text using C#

Tags: c#, html

I want to remove all html tags from a string.i can achieve this using REGX.

but inside the string if it contains number inside the angular braces <100>  it should not remove it .

```
         var withHtml = "<p>hello <b>there<1234></b></p>";
        var withoutHtml = Regex.Replace(withHtml, "\\<[^\\>]*\\>", string.Empty);
```

Result: hello there

but needed output :
hello there 1234

Comment: <1234> is not an html tag...

Comment: yes .but the REGX removes <1234> also because its inside the brackects.I want the number also to display

Comment: Regex don't know which is Valid HTML and which is not. So regex is not the way to do it. Consider using `HTMlAgilityPack`

Comment: Correct HTML would have those two angle brackets around the number escaped/encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example of HTML isn't valid HTML since it contains a non-HTML tag. I figure you intended for the angle-brackets to be encoded.

I don't think regular expressions are suitable for HTML parsing. I recommend using an HTML parser such as [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to do this.

Here's an example:

```
var withHtml = "<p>hello <b>there&lt;1234&gt;</b></p>";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(withHtml);

var withoutHtml = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(document.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

Just add the HtmlAgilityPack NuGet package and a reference to System.Xml to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this in one regular expression, or that a regex is really the correct way as others have suggested. A simple improvement that gets you almost there is:

```
Regex.Replace(withHtml, "\\<[^\\>0-9]*\\>", string.Empty);
```

Gives "hello there<1234>" You then just need to replace all angled brackets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454